# same structure - DDS vs DDL - File and level id's

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, ddl

In IBM i (as/400), I want same program to run against DDL and DDS created files (tables). Using "CALL qsys2.generate_sql" API I was able to convert DDS to DLL.
However once compiled, I get different File and member level id's.

Here is very simple example of DDS and DLL code...

```
A          R TST_RC                                    
A            ORDER_NUM      8S 0       TEXT('ORFER_NO')    
A            ORDER_CUST    20A         TEXT('CUST NO')
```

..

```
CREATE TABLE MYLIB.MYTABLE (                                               
   ORDER_NUM NUMERIC(8, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
   ORDER_CUST CHAR(20) CCSID 37 NOT NULL DEFAULT '' )      
   RCDFMT TST_RC ;   
;
```

Comment: Hello, Can you give more information as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: taking legacy AS/400 DDS table and converting to SQL equivalent is such a way that file level ID does not change... see https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-sql-indexs-and-native-io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file and member level identifier will always be different. That is not a problem, but if the formats are the same, the Format Level Identifier will be the same. It is the format level identifier that causes the level check. So in your example, the file and member level identifiers are different, but the two files will have the same format level identifier, that is 332FE538F73DB on my system. It should even be the same as the format level on your system. Thus the files can be used interchangeably without experiencing level checks.

Using DSPFD, here's what you need to look for
[image: screenshot of DSPFD output]